# How to count number of avx and avx2 instruction set

Tags: assembly, x86, avx, avx2

The number of `Intel SSE4.2` is exactly 313 assembly instruction sets(sum the Intel manual numbers). I want the same number for `AVX` and `AVX2` but couldn't find any trusted reference. I found a [reference](https://www.lri.fr/%7Efalcou/pub/pact-2012.pdf) that tells there are 292 instructions in `AVX` (page 1, Table 1)  and its wrong and SSE4.2 is containing SSSE3 that they didn't count it. So how can I count the `AVX/AVX2` instructions?
(I thought to write a program and copy the Intel intrinsics guide to a text file and process it. But I need an easier way

Comment: Do you want to count number of mnemonics, or number of opcodes?  Do you want to count [VPCMPISTRI](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPISTRI.html) as separate from PCMPISTRI, even though there's still only a 128b version of it in AVX2?

Comment: Do you want to count all the different forms of FMA (like VFMADD132PS vs. VFMADD213PS vs. VFMADDSUB231PS) as separate instructions?  Basically, what do you want to use this number for, and what do you want it to mean?

Comment: @PeterCordes yes I want to be the first comment separated, and the second seperated  and want mnemonics. no just want the new instruction. for example `SSE` introduced 70 new instructions (mmx had 57 instructions) , `SSE2`--->144,  `SSE3` ---> 13,  `SSSE3`---->32, `SSE4` ----> 54 So `AVX`----> ? and `AVX2`----->?

Comment: I want this information to compare the past Intel SIMD technology and `AVX` or `AVX2`. researching for publishing an article

Comment: **There are scripts to parse Intels PDF instruction-set ref manual: http://github.com/zneak/x86doc**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 86 instructions in `AVX` and 137 instructions in `AVX2` and totally 223 new instructions introduced by `AVX` and `AVX2`.
I've copied the Intel intrinsics guide to a word format, deleted intrinsics functions, sorted the assembly instructions and deleted the duplicated instructions. 
This assumes that all instructions have corresponding intrinsics

`AVX` ins: 
vaddpd,
vaddps,
vaddsubpd,
vaddsubps,
vandnpd,
vandnps,
vandpd,
vandps,
vblendpd,
vblendps,
vblendvpd,
vblendvps,
vbroadcastf128,
vbroadcastsd,
vbroadcastss,
vcmppd,
vcmpps,
vcmpsd,
vcmpss,
vcvtdq2pd,
vcvtdq2ps,
vcvtpd2dq,
vcvtpd2ps,
vcvtps2dq,
vcvtps2pd,
vcvttpd2dq,
vcvttps2dq,
vdivpd,
vdivps,
vdpps,
vextractf128,
vhaddpd,
vhaddps,
vhsubpd,
vhsubps,
vinsertf128,
vlddqu,
vmaskmovpd,
vmaskmovps,
vmaxpd,
vmaxps,
vminpd,
vminps,
vmovapd,
vmovaps,
vmovddup,
vmovdqa,
vmovdqu,
vmovmskpd,
vmovmskps,
vmovntdq,
vmovntpd,
vmovntps,
vmovshdup,
vmovsldup,
vmovupd,
vmovups,
vmulpd,
vmulps,
vorpd,
vorps,
vperm2f128,
vpermilpd,
vpermilps,
vptest,
vpxor,
vrcpps,
vroundpd,
vroundps,
vrsqrtps,
vshufpd,
vshufps,
vsqrtpd,
vsqrtps,
vsubpd,
vsubps,
vtestpd,
vtestps,
vunpckhpd,
vunpckhps,
vunpcklpd,
vunpcklps,
vxorpd,
vxorps,
vzeroall,
vzeroupper,

and `AVX2` ins : 
movddup,
vbroadcasti128,
vextracti128,
vgatherdpd,
vgatherdps,
vgatherqpd,
vgatherqps,
vinserti128,
vmovntdqa,
vmpsadbw,
vpabsb,
vpabsd,
vpabsw,
vpackssdw,
vpacksswb,
vpackusdw,
vpackuswb,
vpaddb,
vpaddd,
vpaddq,
vpaddsb,
vpaddsw,
vpaddusb,
vpaddusw,
vpaddw,
vpalignr,
vpand,
vpandn,
vpavgb,
vpavgw,
vpblendd,
vpblendvb,
vpblendw,
vpbroadcastb,
vpbroadcastd,
vpbroadcastq,
vpbroadcastw,
vpcmpeqb,
vpcmpeqd,
vpcmpeqq,
vpcmpeqw,
vpcmpgtb,
vpcmpgtd,
vpcmpgtq,
vpcmpgtw,
vperm2i128,
vpermd,
vpermpd,
vpermps,
vpermq,
vpgatherdd,
vpgatherdq,
vpgatherqd,
vpgatherqq,
vphaddd,
vphaddsw,
vphaddw,
vphsubd,
vphsubsw,
vphsubw,
vpmaddubsw,
vpmaddwd,
vpmaskmovd,
vpmaskmovq,
vpmaxsb,
vpmaxsd,
vpmaxsw,
vpmaxub,
vpmaxud,
vpmaxuw,
vpminsb,
vpminsd,
vpminsw,
vpminub,
vpminud,
vpminuw,
vpmovmskb,
vpmovsxbd,
vpmovsxbq,
vpmovsxbw,
vpmovsxdq,
vpmovsxwd,
vpmovsxwq,
vpmovzxbd,
vpmovzxbq,
vpmovzxbw,
vpmovzxdq,
vpmovzxwd,
vpmovzxwq,
vpmuldq,
vpmulhrsw,
vpmulhuw,
vpmulhw,
vpmulld,
vpmullw,
vpmuludq,
vpor,
vpsadbw,
vpshufb,
vpshufd,
vpshufhw,
vpshuflw,
vpsignb,
vpsignd,
vpsignw,
vpslld,
vpslldq,
vpsllq,
vpsllvd,
vpsllvq,
vpsllw,
vpsrad,
vpsravd,
vpsraw,
vpsrld,
vpsrldq,
vpsrlq,
vpsrlvd,
vpsrlvq,
vpsrlw,
vpsubb,
vpsubd,
vpsubq,
vpsubsb,
vpsubsw,
vpsubusb,
vpsubusw,
vpsubw,
vpunpckhbw,
vpunpckhdq,
vpunpckhqdq,
vpunpckhwd,
vpunpcklbw,
vpunpckldq,
vpunpcklqdq,
vpunpcklwd,
vpxor.

Comment: This assumes that all instructions have corresponding intrinsics.

Comment: I don't see `vmovss`, [the AVX version of MOVSS (`_mm_move_ss`)](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSS.html) in your list.  I guess your method will only count instructions that have a new intrinsic in AVX, e.g. for a 256b version, instead of just for a 3-operand version.  @CodyGray has a good point.

Comment: This might or might not be what the OP wants.  There's a bit of a language barrier, so it's still not totally clear.

Comment: Yes, you are right, There wasn't intrinsic instruction for `vmovss` in Intel Intrinsics Guide and my method didn't count it.

Comment: @PeterCordes where can I find those instruction organizes to improve my answer?

Comment: Intel's insn set manual (x86 manual volume 2).  Link to the PDF in the [x86 tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info),  or see one of the HTML extracts from it, like  [FelixCloutier's](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/).  Actually that reminds me: **the scripts to scrape Intel's PDF into a parseable format are open-source: https://github.com/zneak/x86doc**

Answer (score 1):

[This resource](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/43/e0/Intel_AVX_New_Frontiers_in_Performance_Improvements_and_Energy_Efficiency_WP.pdf) also provide an answer to this question:

> Intel AVX is a comprehensive ISA enhancement that adds n
>   ew functionality in addition 
>   to the compact new encoding format.
>
> • A large number (200+) of legacy Intel SSEx instruction s are
>   upgraded by the  enhanced instruction encoding to take advantage of
>   feat ures like a distinct source  operand and flexible memory
>   alignment.
>
> • A moderate number (< 100) of legacy 128-bit Intel SS Ex instruction
>   have been  promoted to process 256-bit vector data.
>
> **• A number of new data processing and arithmetic operatio ns (< 100),
>   not present  in legacy Intel SSEx, are added to Intel processors to 
>   be launched in 2010 and  beyond.**